# do I need radiator for Raspberry PI 3 model B

Tags: pi-3, cpu, cooling

I am going to build cluster with Raspberry Pi 3 Model B.
I am going to buy dozen of raspberry. and I wanted to know if I need
radiator too

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any cooling for normal Pi usage.  If the Pi is in danger of overheating it will throttle back the CPU to cool down.

If you plan and need to run the Pi at maximum speed continuously then cooling will be useful.  Cooling will lessen the need to throttle the CPU because of overheating.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any cooling for normal use, on my experience I have a PI3 connected to 10 relay and a web server running continuous and the voltage regulators corner are a little bit hotter but the ICs are completely cool.

Answer (score 0):

I have heatsinks on both chips for my Pi3. I don't know if it really needs them or not for my usage, but better safe than sorry. The last thing I need is for the Pi3 to throttle itself back and leave me wondering why it's slower than it's supposed to be. Heatsinks are only a dollar or two.

Answer (score 0):

Where I work, my Pi is running like 7 hours a day and only gets a little warm over the day. I have 2 heat-sinks glued on the Chips which is completely sufficient.